# Upload-symbol run script show error "error: No API Key or Google Services file provided"

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase, crashlytics

I have integrated firebase crashlytics into myapp

On Fabric folder there is script for uploading dysm file.
When I double clicked in **Upload-symbol** it throws error

> error: No API Key or Google Services file provided.

I have re-added Googleinfo.plist file.
API key is proper I have checked

Comment: did you find the solution?

Comment: same issue for me, when running the script

Answer (score 0):

1- If app was migrated to Firebase then do not remove the API key.
2- If app was onboarded in Firebase using the with Fabric legacy (current) or Firebase Crashlytics (current beta) SDK then you only need 'Googleinfo.plist file'.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't run it by double clicking, because it needs parameters in order to run.

**Instead:**

1. Create a zip file with your debug symbols. More on this **below**
2. Open terminal, go to the path where `upload-symbols` sits.
3. Run the script using the following:

   `./upload-symbols -a your_API_key -p your_platform path_to_debug_symbols_zip`

`your_platform` can either be: `ios tvos mac`

If you place the zip file in the folder where upload-symbols sits, then `path_to_debug_symbols_zip` could be: `./DebugSymbols.zip`

**In order to find your debug symbols:**

1. Go to Xcode organizer
2. Select your version's archive
3. Press the `download debug symbols` button on the right
4. Right-click on your version and select 'show in finder'
5. In Finder window, right-click the file and select 'show package contents'
6. Find the dSYMs folder, and create a zip of all files inside.

Comment: I still get the exact same message even after I've provided the API key or the GoogleService-Info.plist location, I'm also getting a command not found message for -a and -p